# Pandas Dataframe can't store in SQLite3 database

Tags: python, pandas

I want to store a Pandas data frame in SQLlite3 database and I wrote this syntax,  `df.to_excel('January.xlsx',sheet_name='output-1')`line is working. but the database is not working. **Temp_data.db** is my database file. its empty after I run my code.

```
    `df=pd.DataFrame(B,index=[dates],columns=['06:00','12:00','18:00','00:00'])
     df.to_excel('January.xlsx',sheet_name='output-1')

    try:
        conn=sqlite3.connect('Temp_data.db')
        c=conn.cursor()
        c.execute('CREATE TABLE TEMP(Date int,06.00 decimal,12.00 decimal,18.00 decimal,00.00 decimal)')
        conn.commit()
        df.to_sql('TEMP',conn,if_exists='replace',index_label='Date')
        c.execute('''
        SELECT * FROM TEMP
        ''')
        for row in c.fetchall():
            print(row)
    except OperationalError:    
        print("Oparational error")
```

Comment: Can you use broader exception to debug. Use `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Answer (score 0):

You just have a problem with the name of your columns in your sqlite database : you need to add quotes around the names like that :

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE TEMP(Date int,'06.00' decimal,'12.00' decimal,'18.00' decimal,'00.00' decimal)")
```